# Is there a GCDASyncSocket version or something that mimics it for the Android?

Tags: android, ios, wifi, gcdasyncsocket

My IOS App uses GCDASyncSocket, but now I need to develop it for the android!
I can develop everything else with ease, but since I am using GCDASyncSocket in my IOS App, making it for Android without GCDASyncSocket or something identical to it for Android will be very improbable. Does anyone have any suggestions?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: have you found it?  I have the question too

Comment: Aahh, No I haven't!  :(